# AsterixDB ERROR: Code: 1 "HYR0010: Node asterix_nc2 does not exist" M1 Mac

Tags: sql, csv

I'm trying to set up a sample cluster with asterixDB on my M1 mac. I have my environment up and running and I am able to successfully make SQL queries with the following code:

```
drop dataverse csv if exists;
create dataverse csv;
use csv;

create type csv_type as {
    lat: int32,
    long: int32
};

create dataset csv_set (csv_type)
  primary key lat;
```

However, when I try to load the dataset with a CSV file it seems to brick my sample cluster and throws the error: Error Code: 1 "HYR0010: Node asterix_nc2 does not exist". The code which causes this is below.

```
use csv;

load dataset csv_set using localfs
    (("path"="127.0.0.1:///Users/nicholassantini/Downloads/test.csv"),
     ("format"="delimited-text"));
```

Thus far I have tried both java's newest release of version 18 and 17.0.3 as well as a variety of ports for the queries. I'm not sure what else to try. Some logs that I think are relevant say that it is failing to connect to the node. Not sure if that's an issue with the port or the node itself. Here is a snippet of those logs.

[image.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAGeg.jpg)

Also in case it matters, my CSV is a simple 2 column 2 row file with all single-digit integer values.

I appreciate any and all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After consulting the developer help email thread, I was able to find that the issue stems from the release of asterixDB that I was using (0.9.7.1). Upgrading to the newest release(0.9.8) fixed this issue.

The link can be found here:
https://ci-builds.apache.org/job/AsterixDB/job/asterixdb-snapshot-integration/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/asterixdb/asterix-server/target/asterix-server-0.9.8-SNAPSHOT-binary-assembly.zip